# It doesn't matter if I have more than one comment. get_comments_number still equal to one?

Tags: comments, count

It doesn't matter if I have more than one comment. get_comments_number still equal to one.

single.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
<div class="container">
<div id="mainbar">

    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h2 class="permalink"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <?php twentyten_posted_on(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

                <div class="entry"><?php the_content('', 'FALSE', ''); ?>

                </div>

                </div>

        <div class="comments-template">
                <?php comments_template(); ?>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
            <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <div class="post">
            <h2><?php _e('Not Found'); ?></h2>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

comments.php:

```
<?php $i;

if ('comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');
if (!empty($post->post_password)) {
    if ($_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH] != $post->post_password) {
?>

<h2><?php _e('Password Protected'); ?></h2>
<p><?php _e('Enter the password to view comments.'); ?></p>

<?php return;
    }
}

$oddcomment = 'alt';
 $i = 0;
if ($comments) : ?>

    <h3 id="comments-title"><?php
    printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number() ),
    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' );
    ?></h3>

<ul class="commentlist">
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
<div class="commenttext  <?php if($i&1) { echo 'odd';} else {echo 'even';} ?>">
<cite>   <?php
   echo get_avatar( $comment, $size = '96', $default = '' );
   ?>

<span class="author"><?php comment_author_link() ?></span><br /><span class="time"><?php comment_time() ?></span> on <a href="#comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" title=""><?php comment_date('F jS, Y') ?></a> <?php edit_comment_link('edit','&nbsp;&nbsp;',''); ?></cite>
<?php comment_text() ?></div>
<?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
<em>Your comment is awaiting moderation.</em>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php
$oddcomment = ( empty( $oddcomment ) ) ? 'class="alt" ' : '';
?>

<?php  endforeach; ?>

</ul>

<?php else : if ('open' == $post->comment_status) :

 else : ?>

<p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>

        <h3 id="respond" class="widgettitle">Leave a Reply</h3>

<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
<p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php the_permalink(); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>

<?php else : ?>

<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

<p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout" title="Log out of this account">Logout &raquo;</a></p>

<?php else : ?>

<p><input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="40" tabindex="1" />
<label for="author"><small>Name <?php if ($req) echo "<em>(required)</em>"; ?></small></label></p>

<p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="40" tabindex="2" />
<label for="email"><small>Email (never published) <?php if ($req) echo "<em>(required)</em>"; ?></small></label></p>

<p><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="40" tabindex="3" />
<label for="url"><small>Website</small></label></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="60" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>

<p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment" />
<input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
</p>

<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

</form>

<?php endif;  ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here

```
>] <h3 id="comments-title"><?php
    printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number() ),
    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' );
    ?></h3>
```

Try changing that to

```
<h3 id="comments-title"><?php
printf( _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' );
?></h3>
```